# Checking null with *ngIf on template is not working

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular project. I try to display an object on a view with a condition to show or hide some DIV.

Below is my component,

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.product = await this.getProductById();
  }

  public async getProductById(): Promise<Product> {
    return this.productService.getProductById<Product>(this.productId);
  }
```

And here is my template,

```
<div class="card__headline">{{product.name}}</div>
<div *ngIf="product.free_trial">
  Free trial from {{product.trial_start}} to {{product.trial_end}}
</div>
```

I got

> free_trial: null

from the API correctly. But the Angular told me error

> "Cannot read property 'free_period' of undefined"

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `product` isn't initialized by the time the HTML is rendered. So it throws the error.

#### Option 1: `async` pipe

Most probably you're using `toPromise()` in the service to convert the observable to promise. If so, I'd say there isn't any need here to do so. You could return the observable as-is and use the Angular [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe in the template to trigger the request. In addition to removing potential memory leaks from open subscriptions, it would also remove the `undefined` error.

**Service**

```js
getProductById(id: any): Observable<Product> {
  return this.http.get<Product>(url);
}
```

**Component**

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  product$: Observable<Product>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.product$ = this.productService.getProductById<Product>(this.productId);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(product$ | async) as product">
  <div class="card__headline">{{ product.name }}</div>
  <div *ngIf="product.free_trial">
    Free trial from {{ product.trial_start }} to {{ product.trial_end }}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

#### Option 2: safe navigation operator

For a quick fix, you could use the Angular safe navigation operator `?.`. It'd check if an object's property is defined before accessing it.

```html
<div class="card__headline">{{ product?.name }}</div>
<div *ngIf="product?.free_trial">
  Free trial from {{ product?.trial_start }} to {{ product?.trial_end }}
</div>
```

Comment: Just some small Addition to this very good answer: the async on OPs ngOnInit() method has no effect whatsoever. Angular does no await on a lifecycle method. I've seen people do this a lot and keep wondering where it is coming from. Angular does not support this afaik.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `optional chaining` on `product`.

```
<div *ngIf="product?.free_trial">
  Free trial from {{product?.trial_start}} to {{product?.trial_end}}
</div>
```